# Spamassassin How to stop domain email containing only numbers?

Tags: spamassassin, spam-filter

There are more and more spams coming from domain containing only number like 23821.com. You can see an example in the message header below.

*Received: from hmdablm ([116.186.123.166]) by 23821.com with MailEnable ESMTP;*

In Spamassassin I could enter one by one the domain to reject to spam but it is a endless job.

Is there a a way (rule, script,...) to do it automatically ?

There is probably a regex code, but I do not know how to write it!

Answer (score 0):

You could use some rules like this

```
header   ALL_NUM_DOMAINS   From =~ /\@(\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+|\d+\.\d+)/
score    ALL_NUM_DOMAINS   10.0
describe ALL_NUM_DOMAINS   Emails from domains with only numbers
```

Comment: No your understand it incorrect. You need to add these rules to your spamassian config

Comment: I did delete my answer because I saw that d means number.
I did put the rule in the config, so fare it is not working, but I will check why and let know.

Comment: Did restarted or reloaded spamassian after adding the rules and in the proper config file?

Comment: Yes, of course local.cf and reload
I did try your regex online at https://regex101.com/ but it did not match, for example any@123.com or any@1a2345.com or any@456any123
So I'm trying to find the regex that fits my problem but I'm not good at this.